# Batch process in SAP HANA (execute one after other)

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-processing, procedure, hana

I am running multiple call procedure functions for nearly 100 people as of now.As am facing memory issues in my system. So,I have separated 20 people in each call function and running one after that.

```
call "schema".procedure_name('p1-p20')
call "schema".procedure_name('p21-p41') 
..
call "schema".procedure_name('p82-p100')
```

I need batch process query. So that once call(p1-p20) is executed, it should automatically run next call function.

So, can someone help it out in HANA or SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all your procedures in a master procedure and call this master procedure in the batch job.